# Calendar with date only expecting, without time of the calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm comparing two dates one is a general date and other is got from gregorian calendar.
when i tried to compare both dates it is giving result false,
Later i realized that it is due to time difference. So even both dates are same and times different i want it to return true or set date of the latter to default.ie,0

```
Eg: Start Date : Wed May 08 00:00:00 CAT 2013  
End Date : Wed May 08 00:40:30 CAT 2013
```

I tried calender API, set(year,month,day,hour,minute,second); but setting year,month and day i don't know.  Please help me this regard to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/java-comparing-two-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474121/i-want-to-get-year-month-day-etc-from-java-date-to-compare-with-gregorian-calen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple java code to get date without time as below. This method will set time part for any date to 00:00:00

```
private Date getDateWithOutTime(Date targetDate) {
    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    newDate.setLenient(false);
    newDate.setTime(targetDate);
    newDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    newDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    newDate.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    newDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    return newDate.getTime();

}
```

Comment: It is possible that the change to the time might actually role the date back or forward a day.  I'd, personally look at setting the time either 1 millisecond before or after midnight, but that's just me +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer above code will not roll date, it will just set time for the date portion.

Comment: And based on the rules of the calendar it "might" roll the date - didn't say it was a high likely hood, just a possibility ;) - I'd be like trying to set the DAY_OF_MONTH to 31 when the calendar is set to February, the calendar will auto just...

Comment: @sagargondhale Thanks for your time with me.. It's working well..

Answer (score 1):

try

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2014,Calendar.JUNE,29,0,0,0);        
        date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Please indicate *why* this answers your question. This question was flagged because its main content is just code.

Comment: This solution is not valid, even risky, because it keeps the milliseconds part, so it won´t compare accurately against other "datetime" values

Answer (score 0):

You can round millis to days and compare them, this will be faster than Calendar based version

```
    long t1 = date1.getTime() / 86400000 * 86400000;
    long t2 = date2.getTime() / 86400000 * 86400000;
    return Long.compare(t1, t2);
```

Comment: The method compare(long, long) is undefined for the type Long

Comment: it's since 1.7, try return t1 > t2 ? 1 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0