# Gradle distZip archive with timestamp

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I use the distZip task to create my distribution. The distribution name is 'baseName'-'version'.zip at the moment. I want to use as classifier the current timestamp, i.e. the time of the build.

I tried using

```
distZip {
    classifier new Date().getTime()
}
```

but then I get the following error:

```
Could not find method classifier() for arguments [1421317243316] on root project
```

Doing the Java trick with

```
new Date().getTime() + ''
```

did not help. Anyone an idea?

Would also be good to know if I can extract year, month and day from the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `classifier` is a property and not a method. Hence, you need to use assignment (`=`) to assign the value to the property.

```
distZip {
    classifier = new Date().getTime()
}
```

To get date components, you can use `Calendar` object in java. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474121/i-want-to-get-year-month-day-etc-from-java-date-to-compare-with-gregorian-calen).

Comment: Ah, it's that simple :)