# How to get only Date value and not time from getDateCellValue

Tags: java, excel, date, datetime

I am trying to read a Date value from xlsx sheet using POI. The date specified in sheet is in MM/DD/YYYY format:

Ex: 12/31/2030

However when I read it with getDateCellValue it comes as :Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2030

I use DateFormat to format it back to MM/DD/YYYY, but the formatted date with the above value becomes

12/31/2031.

Due to the Time read by getCellDateValue as 00:00:00 is changes to next year.However the date and month and not affected, anyway it is fine but how to get rid of that hour, minutes and seconds before formatting it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible similar answer maybe.
[I want to get Year, Month, Day, etc from Java Date to compare with Gregorian Calendar date in Java. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474121/i-want-to-get-year-month-day-etc-from-java-date-to-compare-with-gregorian-calen)