# Validate weekend or non-working day for currency

Tags: java, spring

I receive from UI selected date, not now Date, it's may be different date. 
I need to check weekend and add local  non-working days and check these days too.
I receive:

```
   @RequestParam(value = "valueDate")
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")Date valueDate
```

I can use `valueDate.getDay()`, but how I understand this old format (because getDay() is crossed out). 
How will now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to get Year, Month, Day, etc from Java Date to compare with Gregorian Calendar date in Java. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474121/i-want-to-get-year-month-day-etc-from-java-date-to-compare-with-gregorian-cal)

Comment: java.util.Date API is old and ugly, and most it's methods are deprecated now. 
Use java.time API

Answer (score 2):

Examining `Date`s for features such as day of week etc. is discouraged due to significant issues with edge cases such as time zones etc.

It is recommended that you examine `Date`s using a `Calendar` object, or, for Java 8, the [Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API.

See [I want to get Year, Month, Day, etc from Java Date to compare with Gregorian Calendar date in Java. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9474121/823393) for more details.